# Protecting /etc/passwd and /etc/shadow from concurrent access

Tags: c++, c, linux, passwd

How do I protect /etc/passwd and /etc/shadow from concurrent access?  I don't see any locking mechanism in `pwd.h`.  I see the manual for `pwd_mkdb` mentions obtaining a lock, but is it just locking the file for exclusive access?

Is there a convention for locking these files if I were to write a utility to modify them directly, or through the get/set/endpwent family of functions?

Answer (score 3):

I think most applications use PAM these days, don't they? http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/libs/pam/Linux-PAM-html/Linux-PAM_ADG.html. That said, you might look at the source for `pam_unix.so' to see how they do it. I looked in [pam_unix_passwd.c](http://devel.blueonyx.it/trac/browser/BlueQuartz/5100WG/branches/dev/ui/sauce-basic.mod/src/pam_pwdb/pam_unix_passwd.-c?rev=1) and followed this:

```
/* update the password database(s) -- race conditions..? */

retval = unix_update_db(pamh, ctrl, user, pass_old, pass_new);
```

To [here](http://devel.blueonyx.it/trac/browser/NewQuartz/5106R/ui/sauce-basic.mod/src/pam_pwdb/pam_unix_pwupd.-c?rev=2) which has a lot of functions prefixed `pwdb'. Googling again revealed [this](https://fedorahosted.org/passwd/browser/pwdb.c) which I think is the source for [passwd](https://fedorahosted.org/passwd/browser/).

As a result, I think editing these files is handled by `libpwdb`. Certainly I see includes to:

```
#include <pwdb/pwdb_public.h>
#include <pwdb/pwdb_shadow.h>
```

But `find . -name "*pwdb*" 2>/dev/null` has turned up nothing on my system so far.